# Request from Apple Watch takes an absurd amount of time

Tags: ios, watchkit

In my apple watch application I am making a request to location services and to a web service. Performing both these tasks on the iPhone takes roughly 2 seconds, at most. However, when I am making the same requests from the Apple watch it takes more than 10 seconds before I get a reply...unless the iPhone application is already running in which case the request takes about 2 seconds.

I figure there is something wrong with my background task in `application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:` but I cannot figure out what. All hints are appreciated.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply
{
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier identifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

    dispatch_block_t endBlock = ^ {
        if (identifier != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
            [application endBackgroundTask:identifier];
        }
        identifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    };

    identifier = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:endBlock];

    reply = ^(NSDictionary *replyInfo) {
        reply(replyInfo);
        endBlock();
    };

    // Call location services with completion block ^{
        // Use the location and make request to web service
        // with completion ^{

            // reply(@{@"info" : @"here be dragons"});

        // };
    //};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to save power, the Apple watch limits the update frequency for location services (a major power hog). When you open the iPhone application, you prioritize the task you're running, and the Apple watch will update its location more often.

You can try to force the application to update faster by sending a "wake up" ping: send an empty/dummy call to the application and reply with a dummy reply. This should wake up the connection for a while, and your second call might be processed faster, although I am unsure of whether this "wake up" ping will prioritize location services.

Last thing, IMHO 10 seconds isn't really an "absurd" amount of time.